# NetTrain & SoftmaxLayer: Expected a vector of indices

Tags: neural-networks

Is SoftmaxLayer broken in version 11.3.0.0?  I know, it's probably me.  Here's a MWE of the issue.

[image]

Note that this works fine if e.g. Exp is substituted for SoftmaxLayer[].

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It works if you explicitly specify the loss function:

```
NetTrain[testnet, {{1, 2} -> {0.2, 0.8}}, 
 LossFunction -> CrossEntropyLossLayer["Binary"]]
```

The default is `Automatic`, which chooses `CrossEntropyLossLayer["Index"]` and expects indices as training targets.

From the documentation of [LossFunction](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LossFunction.html):

> When a loss layer is chosen automatically for a port, the loss layer
>   to use is based on the layer within the net whose output is connected
>   to the port, as follows:
>
> `SoftmaxLayer[]` -> use `CrossEntropyLossLayer["Index"]`
>
> `ElementwiseLayer[LogisticSigmoid]` -> use `CrossEntropyLossLayer["Binary"]`
>
> `NetPairEmbeddingOperator[]`  -> use `ContrastiveLossLayer[]`
>
> other non-loss layers -> use `MeanSquaredLossLayer[]`
>
> loss layers -> use unchanged