# Trying to train a NetGraph network generates an error

Tags: neural-networks, version-12.2

I'm trying to learn neural networks in the Wolfram language, so I've written the following code.
The input is a $2*3$ matrix, split into two parts. The parts are given to distinct linear layers, then the results concatenated and soft-maxed.

```
g1 = NetGraph[<|  "c" -> CatenateLayer[], "s" -> SoftmaxLayer[],
    "p1" -> PartLayer[1,"Input" -> {2, 3}], "p2" -> PartLayer[2, "Input" -> {2, 3}],
     "l1" -> LinearLayer[1], "l2" ->  LinearLayer[1]|>,
   {NetPort["input"] -> "p1" -> "l1", 
    NetPort["input"] -> "p2" -> "l2", 
    {"l1", "l2"} -> "c" -> "s" ->  NetPort["output"]}];

g2 = NetInitialize[g1]
g2[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}]
NetTrain[g2, {{{1, 2, 3}, {4,5,6}} -> {0.2, 0.8}}]
```

Initializations and initial evaluations work,
but training does not. This gives the following error:
[image: network error]
I don't know what's causing it or how to fix it. The network seems correct as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this answer: [NetTrain & SoftmaxLayer: Expected a vector of indices](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/175575/nettrain-softmaxlayer-expected-a-vector-of-indices).

Comment: I've missed the bracket in the post but not in the actual notebook code I was running. I've corrected it now. Try and run the code to see if the bug occurs.

Comment: Works for me on 12.1.1.0 (OS X). Maybe try restarting WL.

Comment: I am using 12.2. I will try restarting.

Comment: Ok, wait, I see what you mean (my messages window was hidden). Does this post resolve the issue for you? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/175575/nettrain-softmaxlayer-expected-a-vector-of-indices

Comment: Yes. Explicitly specifying the loss function does fix the error. Thank you.